# iOS Collection view cell update is delaying

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have sample collection view. I am dequeue cell from it by `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`
When ViewController is loaded the OS dequeue 5 cells and load information on it.
When I scroll, another 5-7 cells are dequeued and information is loaded on it.
The second set of loaded cells is coming in foreground with information from first set of loaded cells and the information in them is updated with fresh (right) one after less than a half second.

I am using `prepareForReuse` for cells, where I reset visibility of all cell components and than load fresh information, but the result is not what I expect, it is what I described above.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

EDIT: Well if I update cell views with data from `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` all works fine, but if I pass the data to cell and ask cell to modify itself - than I have a problem pointed above.

EDIT 2: Soved. As I imagine - it was stupid mistake. As advice for others - make sure that you pass data to cell in any cases.

Comment: Any reason why you are not updating your stuff in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I am using <code>cellForItemAtIndexPath:</code> to dequeue cells and  to set needed information. Did you mean that I need to execute logic which is currently in <code> prepareForReuse </code> from <code>cellForItemAtIndexPath:</code> and then set needed information?

Comment: That's what I mean. Ditch `prepareForReuse`and move the code into `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I moved code from 'prepareForReuse' to some like 'resetCellUI' and call it from 'cellForItemAtIndexPath:', there is no change in the result. The effect is observed only once (when OS caching information). After first time all cells is loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ALLOC statements in cellForItemAtIndexPath?  or if using a subclass, do you have any ALLOC's in the subclass implementation?  Possibly you seeing ui elements that are not being cleared out.

Comment: No, here is cell init 'MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:myIde                                                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
'

Comment: Cell views are in .xib file and I have weak IBOutlets to them.